# iCloud uses a different container on watchOS 3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cloudkit, watchos-3

I'm trying to get iCloud to work between iPhone and the Apple Watch (using CloudKit on watchOS 3). I have specified the cloud container in the Watch Extension to be the same as the one in the iOS target, but when running the app, I get this error from a query I made:

```
Failure retrieving: Optional(<CKError 0x17d45cf0: "Unknown Item" (11/2003); server message = "did not find record type recordTypeId="Recommendation""; uuid = 37D53C78-FF19-4CE3-80BD-C1990F0135A2; container ID = "iCloud.mathsrobot.MathsRobot-LearnMaths.watchkitapp.watchkitextension">)
```

From the container ID, I can tell that it is not using the iOS app container, which should be `iCloud.mathsrobot.MathsRobot-LearnMaths`. How can I make it use the iCloud container for the iOS app?

**iOS target capabilities screenshot** [Main iOS target capabilities with iCloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS3Jf.png)

**Watch target capabilities screenshot** [Watch Extension target capabilities with iCloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8RDI.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely you are using the default container in your code ...

```
container = CKContainer.default()
```

Which will default to the watchOS app's container ID, even if you set it in Xcode. You should try to do something like this ...

```
container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.mathsrobot.MathsRobot-LearnMaths")
```